# How to draw "graphs of posets" in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Any idea on how to draw the following graphs?

[image: Graphs of posets]

The black dots mean the two elements are comparing. Graphs of posets is a collapsed version of a decision tree.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: An "idea on how to draw the ... graphs": Try the packages `tikz`, `pgf`, `pstricks`, and maybe `tikz-qtree`. When you are done with trying and didn't find a solution, come back here and report your findings by updating your question with an MWE (cf. ChrisS' comment). Knowledgeable people will try to help you in your undertaking. 加油！